# How to do an almost-postback in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't know what to call this, except that it is almost-a-postback. I'd like my rails app to be able to receive a request independently from somewhere else on the interweb in the form of:

```
myapp.com/count?id=45&sex=y
```

And to be able to perform some calculations (update some table etc) and not bother to respond back.

The **key** here is - I just want to perform the action and nothing else, not display any view or redirect to any other page.

I set up a "count" controller, but it wants some view or web page to go to. Then I thought, maybe routes could do it? But that seems like a bad idea to have code in routes.

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your method controller do this:

```
def method_count
  #do calculation stuff
  render :nothing => true
end
```

This will return status 200 (if everything was ok) and nothing will be rendered.

Don't forget to setup your route in config/routes.rb

Answer (score 1):

For API calls it is a good idea to return only an HTTP status code if no content has been requested. You can do this using the [`head` method in ActionController::Base](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Head.html#method-i-head).

```
def count
  # do work
  head :success
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a controller and put your action into it !

In config/routes.rb :

```
get "yourcontroller/count"
```

In yourcontroller.rb :

```
def count
  #some code treating params
end
```

Comment: Got that, but the controller wants to go pass control on to a view, and I don't want *any* view, or even any other website - I want to just process the request and nothing else.

Comment: Try to end your action with 
    "render :nothing => true"

Comment: HTTP requests must always have a response. Just send a response with nothing interesting in it. The end making the request can ignore the response.